# Difficult bug in my 2D Compressible Euler solver

Tags: finite-difference, fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, numerics, numerical-modelling

For the past few days, I have been writing a numerical solver for the 2D compressible Euler equations for an ideal gas.  My numerical method has been the Local Lax Friedrichs or "Rusanov's method." Before writing the 2D code I successfully wrote a 1D code using the Local Lax-Friedrichs method, which works. However, my extension to 2D has given me some problems I am struggling with no success.  In terms of the specific error, I keep getting NaNs in my arrays (for $\rho$,$u$, $v$, $E$, $p$). I have attached my code below.

To better understand whats going on in the code the method I am using is

\begin{align}
Q_{i,j}^{n+1} &= Q_{i,j}^{n} - \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x} \left(F_{i+1/2,j}^{n} - F_{i-1/2,j}^{n} \right) - \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta y} \left(G_{i,j+1/2}^{n} - G_{i,j-1/2}^{n}\right)\\
F_{i+1/2,j}^{n} &= \frac{1}{2} \left[ \left(F_{i+1,j}^{n} + F_{i,j}^{n}\right) - a_{i+1/2,j} \left(Q_{i+1,j}^{n} - Q_{i,j}^{n} \right)\right]\\
a_{i+1/2,j} &= \max{\left(\left|u_{i,j}\right| + c_{i,j}, \left|u_{i+1,j}\right| + c_{i+1,j}\right)}\\
G_{i,j+1/2}^{n} &= \frac{1}{2} \left[ \left(G_{i,j+1}^{n} - G_{i,j}^{n}\right) - b_{i,j+1/2}\left(Q_{i,j+1}^{n} - Q_{i,j}^{n}\right) \right]\\
b_{i,j+1/2} &= \max{\left(\left|v_{i,j}\right| + c_{i,j}, \left|v_{i,j+1}\right| + c_{i,j+1}\right)}
\end{align}

In terms of $c_{i,j}$, this term refers to the speed of sound, i.e. $c_{i,j} = \sqrt{\frac{\gamma p}{\rho}}$ Our pressure can be defined as

$p = (\gamma - 1)(E - \frac{\rho}{2} \left(u^{2} + v^{2}\right)\\
E = \frac{p}{\gamma-1} + \frac{\rho}{2} \left(u^{2} + v^{2}\right)\\
Q = [\rho\;\rho u\;\rho v\;E]^{T}\\
F = [\rho u\; \rho u^{2} + p\; \rho u v\; u(E+p)]^{T}\\
G = [\rho v\; \rho u v\; \rho v^{2} + p\; v(E+p)]^{T}
$

```
nx = 101;
dx = 1/(nx-1);

ny = 101;
dy = 1/(ny-1);

r = zeros(nx,ny);
u = zeros(nx,ny);
v = zeros(nx,ny);
E = zeros(nx,ny);
p = zeros(nx,ny);

x = zeros(nx,ny);
y = zeros(nx,ny);

Q = zeros(nx,ny,4);
Qnew = zeros(nx,ny,4);

F = zeros(nx,ny,4);
G = zeros(nx,ny,4);

Fh = zeros(nx-1,ny,4);
Gh = zeros(nx,ny-1,4);

gamma = 1.4;

c = zeros(nx,ny);
ah1 = zeros(nx,ny);
ah2 = zeros(nx,ny);

CFL = 0.5;
tMax = 0.25;

for j=1:ny
    for i=1:nx
        x(i,j) = (i-1)*dx;
        y(i,j) = (j-1)*dy;
    end
end

for j=1:ny
    for i=1:nx
        if (x(i,j) >= 0.5 && y(i,j) >= 0.5)
            p(i,j) = 0.4; 
            r(i,j) = 0.5313; 
            u(i,j) = 0.0; 
            v(i,j) = 0.0;
        elseif (x(i,j) < 0.5 && y(i,j) >= 0.5)
             p(i,j) = 1.0; 
            r(i,j) = 1.0; 
            u(i,j) = 0.7276; 
            v(i,j) = 0.0;
        elseif (x(i,j) < 0.5 && y(i,j) < 0.5)
            p(i,j) = 1.0; 
            r(i,j) = 0.8; 
            u(i,j) = 0.0; 
            v(i,j) = 0.0;
        elseif (x(i,j) >= 0.5 && y(i,j) < 0.5)
            p(i,j) = 1.0; 
            r(i,j) = 1.0; 
            u(i,j) = 0.0; 
            v(i,j) = 0.7276;
        end

        c(i,j) = sqrt((gamma*p(i,j))/r(i,j));
    end
end

Eig1 = abs(u) + c;
Eig2 = abs(v) + c;

dt = CFL*dx./max(Eig1(:),Eig2(:));
nt = floor(tMax/dt);

for k=1:nt
    for j=1:ny
        for i=1:nx
            E(i,j) = p(i,j)./(gamma-1) + (0.5*r(i,j))*(u(i,j).^2 + v(i,j).^2);

            Q(i,j,1) = r(i,j);
            Q(i,j,2) = r(i,j).*u(i,j);
            Q(i,j,3) = r(i,j).*v(i,j);
            Q(i,j,4) = E(i,j);

            F(i,j,1) = r(i,j).*u(i,j);
            F(i,j,2) = r(i,j).*u(i,j).^2 + p(i,j);
            F(i,j,3) = r(i,j).*u(i,j).*v(i,j);
            F(i,j,4) = u(i,j).*(E(i,j) + p(i,j));

            G(i,j,1) = r(i,j).*v(i,j);
            G(i,j,2) = r(i,j).*v(i,j).*u(i,j);
            G(i,j,3) = r(i,j).*v(i,j).^2 + p(i,j);
            G(i,j,4) = v(i,j).*(E(i,j) + p(i,j));
        end
    end

    for j=1:ny-1
        for i=1:nx-1
            ah1(i,j) = max(abs(u(i,j)) + c(i,j), abs(u(i+1,j)) + c(i+1,j));
            ah2(i,j) = max(abs(v(i,j)) + c(i,j), abs(v(i,j+1)) + c(i,j+1));

            Fh(i,j,:) = 0.5*(F(i+1,j,:) + F(i,j,:) - ah1(i,j).*(Q(i+1,j,:) - Q(i,j,:)));
            Gh(i,j,:) = 0.5*(G(i,j,:) + G(i,j+1,:) - ah2(i,j).*(Q(i,j+1,:) - Q(i,j,:)));

        end
    end

    Qnew(:,1,:)  = Qnew(:,2,:);      
    Qnew(1,:,:)  = Qnew(2,:,:);
    Qnew(:,ny,:) = Qnew(:,ny-1,:);    
    Qnew(nx,:,:) = Qnew(nx-1,:,:);

    for j=2:ny-1
        for i=2:nx-1
            Qnew(i,j,:) = Q(i,j,:) - (dt/dx)*(Fh(i,j,:) - Fh(i-1,j,:)) - (dt/dy)*(Gh(i,j,:) - Gh(i,j-1,:));
        end
    end  

    Q = Qnew; 
    r = Qnew(:,:,1);
    u = Qnew(:,:,2)./Qnew(:,:,1);
    v = Qnew(:,:,3)./Qnew(:,:,1);
    E = Qnew(:,:,4);
    p = (gamma-1)*(E - (0.5*Qnew(:,:,1))*(u.^2 + v.^2));
end

figure(1) 
contour(x,y,r);
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
title('Density');
```

In terms of the initial condition, it divides the discrete domain into 4 regions, i.e. 4 quadrants.

My code does "run," but it only plots the initial condition which means there's something going wrong in my time update (however for my 1D problem it works with no problem.) My density plot **should** look like this:

[image]

What we should expect in terms of ($\rho$, $u$, $v$, $p$) is something similar to the picture I uploaded. The problem I am solving is a test problem which tests the accuracy of numerical solvers (Wendroff & Liska 2003)

Comment: Your code works fine for me (MATLAB 2015a). Add `clear all` at the beginning to be sure to clear all variables when you re-run your code. I indeed get 4 quadrants but can you explain what we should find in term of (r,u,v,p) ? I would have written `dt = CFL*min(dx,dy)./max(Eig1(:),Eig2(:));` if the number of nodes in x and y direction is not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your time step `dt` is a matrix. That is not possible. Just below your calculate the number of required time step to reach `tMax`. You do not know that. You do not know how many time step you will require to complete your simulation, it depends on the velocity field and the speed of sound.
The time step is linked to the mesh size and the maximum velocity through the CFL condition such that, for the Euler problem :
$$
dt = CFL \frac{h}{\vert \vert \mathbf{u} \vert \vert + c}
$$
where h is the size of the cell. Notice here that we deal with the norm of the velocity, not the absolute value. In 1D, the absolute value works, you were just lucky.
To find the largest admissible time step, you need to compute the maximum velocity (that is to say $max(\vert \vert \mathbf{u} \vert \vert + c)$) through your computational domain because each cell will have a different velocity. If your mesh is uniformly spaced, it is the cell with the maximum velocity that will dictate the maximum time step allowed. This process absolutely need to be inside your loop in time at the beginning of each iteration, your `dt` will vary through time and it is a scalar, not a matrix that will change at each iteration.

Second, your boundary conditions are not properly set. Actually, you iterate through all your cells except ones on the boundaries which have a value of zero at the first iteration because of your initialization of $Q_{new}$. Add `keyboard` just before the end of the time loop and check your workspace, you will see that u and v are NaN because you have divided by 0.

BC are difficult to handle, a common solution is to add ghost cells with a virtual state so you don't need to separate the computation of the boundary cells, or directly impose the flux on the boundary.

**EDIT :**

The following piece of code works for me, however I can't ensure you it is bug-free. I usually work with an isothermal Euler model so I don't know if my energy equation is implemented in the right way. Double-check the pressure law and notation between $E$ and $e$ to be sure.

```
clear all;
close all;
clc; 

nx = 101;
ny = 101;

% Initialization
r = zeros(nx,ny);
u = zeros(nx,ny);
v = zeros(nx,ny);
E = zeros(nx,ny);
p = zeros(nx,ny);

x = zeros(nx,ny);
y = zeros(nx,ny);

Q = zeros(nx,ny,4);
F = zeros(nx,ny,4);
G = zeros(nx,ny,4);

Fh = zeros(nx-1,ny,4);
Gh = zeros(nx,ny-1,4);

Qnew = zeros(nx,ny,4);

c = zeros(nx,ny);
ah1 = zeros(nx,ny);
ah2 = zeros(nx,ny);

% Parameters
gamma = 1.4;
CFL = 0.5;
tMax = 0.25;
dx = 1/(nx-1);
dy = 1/(ny-1);

% Creating mesh
for j=1:ny
    for i=1:nx
        x(i,j) = (i-1)*dx;
        y(i,j) = (j-1)*dy;
    end
end

% Initial condition
for j=1:ny
    for i=1:nx
        if (x(i,j) >= 0.5 && y(i,j) >= 0.5)
            p(i,j) = 0.4; 
            r(i,j) = 0.5313; 
            u(i,j) = 0.0; 
            v(i,j) = 0.0;
        elseif (x(i,j) < 0.5 && y(i,j) >= 0.5)
            p(i,j) = 1.0; 
            r(i,j) = 1.0; 
            u(i,j) = 0.7276; 
            v(i,j) = 0.0;
        elseif (x(i,j) < 0.5 && y(i,j) < 0.5)
            p(i,j) = 1.0; 
            r(i,j) = 0.8; 
            u(i,j) = 0.0; 
            v(i,j) = 0.0;
        elseif (x(i,j) >= 0.5 && y(i,j) < 0.5)
            p(i,j) = 1.0; 
            r(i,j) = 1.0; 
            u(i,j) = 0.0; 
            v(i,j) = 0.7276;
        end
        E(i,j) = p(i,j)./(gamma-1) + 0.5*r(i,j)*(u(i,j).^2+v(i,j).^2);
        c(i,j) = sqrt(gamma*p(i,j)/r(i,j));
    end
end

% Q_new will be the solution vector
Qnew(:,:,1)=r;
Qnew(:,:,2)=r.*u;
Qnew(:,:,3)=r.*v;
Qnew(:,:,4)=E;

t=0.d0;
% Time loop
while (t<tMax)
    dt = CFL*min(dx,dy)./(max(max(c+sqrt(u.*u+v.*v)))); % Compute time step
    for j=1:ny
        for i=1:nx

            % Flux calculation
            Q(i,j,1) = r(i,j);
            Q(i,j,2) = r(i,j).*u(i,j);
            Q(i,j,3) = r(i,j).*v(i,j);
            Q(i,j,4) = E(i,j);

            F(i,j,1) = r(i,j).*u(i,j);
            F(i,j,2) = r(i,j).*u(i,j).^2 + p(i,j);
            F(i,j,3) = r(i,j).*u(i,j).*v(i,j);
            F(i,j,4) = u(i,j).*(E(i,j) + p(i,j));

            G(i,j,1) = r(i,j).*v(i,j);
            G(i,j,2) = r(i,j).*v(i,j).*u(i,j);
            G(i,j,3) = r(i,j).*v(i,j).^2 + p(i,j);
            G(i,j,4) = v(i,j).*(E(i,j) + p(i,j));
        end
    end

    % Rusanov method
    for j=1:ny-1
        for i=1:nx-1
            ah1(i,j) = max(abs(u(i,j)) + c(i,j), abs(u(i+1,j)) + c(i+1,j));
            ah2(i,j) = max(abs(v(i,j)) + c(i,j), abs(v(i,j+1)) + c(i,j+1));

            Fh(i,j,:) = 0.5*(F(i+1,j,:) + F(i,j,:) - ah1(i,j).*(Q(i+1,j,:) - Q(i,j,:)));
            Gh(i,j,:) = 0.5*(G(i,j,:) + G(i,j+1,:) - ah2(i,j).*(Q(i,j+1,:) - Q(i,j,:)));

        end
    end

    % Advance the solution in time
    for j=2:ny-1
        for i=2:nx-1
            Qnew(i,j,:) = Qnew(i,j,:) - (dt/dx)*(Fh(i,j,:) - Fh(i-1,j,:)) - (dt/dy)*(Gh(i,j,:) - Gh(i,j-1,:));
        end
    end 

    % Boundary condition
    Qnew(:,1,:)  = Qnew(:,2,:);      
    Qnew(1,:,:)  = Qnew(2,:,:);
    Qnew(:,ny,:) = Qnew(:,ny-1,:);    
    Qnew(nx,:,:) = Qnew(nx-1,:,:);

    % Primitive variables
    r = Qnew(:,:,1);
    u = Qnew(:,:,2)./r;
    v = Qnew(:,:,3)./r;
    E = Qnew(:,:,4);
    p = (gamma-1)*(E-0.5*r.*(u.*u+v.*v));

   t=t+dt % Advance in time

end

% Plot
figure(1) 
contour(x(2:nx-1,2:nx-1),y(2:nx-1,2:nx-1),r(2:nx-1,2:nx-1));
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
title('Density');
```

The main changes are the `while` time loop and the computation of `dt`. Also I have slightly changed your boundary conditions (moving after the update in time). Actually, your mesh now incorporates ghost cells for cells indexes i=1,i=nx,j=1 and j=ny. These cells are not part of the computational mesh (the update of the solution occurs for 2:nx-1 and 2:ny-1) but you need them to compute flux. I just copy the updated value from the neighbouring cells as you do before. That is not perfect but I can't investigate much further, you didn't mention the boundary condition for your problem (Dirichlet, Neumann ?). That's why in the `contour` command, I don't plot these cells.

Comment: Hi thank you for the informative answer.  However, there are some things I am not sure about.  1.  Is there any particular norm I should be using (L1, L2, etc?), 2. In terms of calculating my dt considering my problem is 2D, I am assuming my dt would look like dt = CFL*h/norm(u+c,v+c) since we have u and v velocity.

Comment: Sorry my notation is confusing. $\mathbf{u}$ in bold means a vector so $\mathbf{u}=(u,v)$. The norm is the euclidean norm: $\vert \vert \mathbf{u} \vert \vert =\sqrt[]{u^2+v^2}$

Comment: Hi Coriolis, I've read what you said and have implemented the suggestion of how to calculate dt, but am getting no luck.  Aside from the boundary conditions, is there something I am not handling properly?  In terms of the calculation of dt, I've tried very small values (that would be within the criteria of convergence) and am getting NaNs, while when I use your suggested dt I don't get any advancement in time.  Sorry if I am missing someting

Comment: I fixed your boundary conditions (no NaN anymore) but I still got negative pressure. Could you edit your post to add your closure pressure law ? Mention also the components of the vector Q (primitive or conservative variables ?). Have you validated your 1D implementation with a Sod shock tube ?

Comment: Hi Coriolis, I have added the definition of Q.  For both 1D and 2D I implemented the conservative versions of the equations. I have implemented my 1D version of the code for Sod's Shock tube and it works flawlessly.  Would you like me to post the 1D code? it is the same in terms of the way I did my calculations.

Comment: Ah ! If what you edited is true, there are two problems. First you should be dealing with $\rho E$ (conservative), not $E$. Second, as I suspected, your pressure law seems wrong, that is not the ideal gas EoS, it should be $p=\rho E (\gamma-1)$. When fixing that, I managed to make your code converges toward a solution but I don't know if it is the right one.

Comment: Hi Coriolis, Thanks for pointing that out, however from a few places I've looked at, the equations I have are not incorrect (http://people.nas.nasa.gov/~pulliam/Classes/New_notes/euler_notes.pdf - Page 2).  With that said I will try and change it.  Would you mind posting your code so I can see if its converging to the correct solution (taking into account the initial conditions and boundary conditions?)

Comment: Ok I misunderstood. I make a confusion between $E$ the total energy and $e$ the internal energy so your equation are correct. I will check again.

Comment: To my understanding both formulations are correct.  Moreover, I implemented both for my 1D Sod shock tube and both work fine in that I converge to the proper solution.

Comment: I am curious if you could share a plot or results of your fix to my code.  It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have updated my post. Not sure about the relevance of my fix though. I got something; that's a start, maybe you can find the rest for yourself.

Comment: Hi Coriolis, thank you very much for the help.  In terms of the boundary conditions we have Dirichlet boundary conditions (i.e., the conserved quantities take on the values specified by the initial conditions at either boundary).  I will let you know if the fix solved my issue when I get back to a computer with MATLAB

Comment: I managed to fix it.  I actually didnt have to change much of the code except I needed $(r0, u0, v0, p0)$ for the IC and then update it before the main time loop